# Hadoop mapreduce input path does not exists (What filesystem is MR Job looking for?)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying  to run MR job on Hadoop cluster. Once I tried successfully, but from yesterday I can't run the same command, since it cannot find input path

here is trace :

```
[esb99usr@SBT-IPO-078 ~]$ yarn jar /tmp/mihaylov-temp/MR.jar 
ru.sbt.hadoop.mr.data.index.DayDataIndexStart -D ru.sbt.hadoop.mr.map.mb=3072 -D ru.sbt.hadoop.mr.reduce.count=8 -D ru.sbt.hadoop.mr.map.count=80 /nameservices/supercluster/esbLogs/year/2015/months/7/days/27/hrs/18/ /nameservices/supercluster/esbLogs/year/2015/months/7/days/27/sort/ 1440622800966   1440709200966

15/09/03 14:33:37 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at SBT-IPO-077.ca.sbrf.ru/10.116.6.195:8032
15/09/03 14:33:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /nameservices/supercluster/user/esb99usr/.staging/job_1439318575767_0078
15/09/03 14:33:38 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:esb99usr (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: viewfs://cluster16/nameservices/supercluster/esbLogs/year/2015/months/7/days/27/hrs/18
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: viewfs://cluster16/nameservices/supercluster/esbLogs/year/2015/months/7/days/27/hrs/18

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:321)
        ..........


[esb99usr@SBT-IPO-078 ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /nameservices/supercluster/esbLogs/year/2015/months/7/days/27/hrs/18/
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 wasadmin supergroup 1417233459 2015-08-27 21:39 /nameservices/supercluster/esbLogs/year/2015/months/7/days/27/hrs/18/log1.seq
-rw-r--r--   3 wasadmin supergroup    6020096 2015-08-27 21:39 /nameservices/supercluster/esbLogs/year/2015/months/7/days/27/hrs/18/log1.seq.filter
```

So when i run MR job, it claims that input path does not exists, but i can see it via `hadoop dfs -ls /....`. It worked perfectly until yesterday, and there is no evidence that cluster is down, Cloudera says it's up and cluster's health is Good. How this problem can be solved?

Comment: can you check `esb99usr ` belong to `supergroup` group ??

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary yes, it does.

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary btw one can see, that file permissions allow any user to read hdfs files, so i doubt, that chmod is the issue

Comment: Can you try this `yarn jar /tmp/mihaylov-temp/MR.jar 
ru.sbt.hadoop.mr.data.index.DayDataIndexStart -Dru.sbt.hadoop.mr.map.mb=3072 -Dru.sbt.hadoop.mr.reduce.count=8 -Dru.sbt.hadoop.mr.map.count=80 /nameservices/supercluster/esbLogs/year/2015/months/7/days/27/hrs/18/ /nameservices/supercluster/esbLogs/year/2015/months/7/days/27/sort/ 1440622800966   1440709200966`

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary unfortunately, this does not help

Comment: Are you able to browse `hdfs dfs -ls viewfs://cluster16/nameservices/supercluster/esbLogs/year/2015/months/7/days/27/hrs/18` the path ??

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

the command to run the job is

```
]$ yarn jar /tmp/mihaylov-temp/MR.jar (Main Class Name) (input file path) (output directoru path)
```